# Selenium с Яндекс браузером, не удается запустить

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```py
from selenium import webdriver
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

binary_yandex_driver_file = 'yandexdriver.exe' # path to YandexDriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(binary_yandex_driver_file, options=options)
driver.get('https://yandex.ru')
driver.quit()
```

Использую selenium 4.10,получаю ошибку:

```
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(binary_yandex_driver_file, options=options)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: WebDriver.__init__() got multiple values for argument 'options'
```

Не совсем пойму как запустить яндексдрайвер.

Comment: Замени картинки текстами...

Comment: Попробуйте абсолютный путь к файлу драйвера

Answer (score 0):

Ваш пример кода является верным для версий selenium младше 4.10.

Теперь `executable_path` нужно передавать через `service`:

```py
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

binary_yandex_driver_file = 'yandexdriver.exe' # path to YandexDriver

service = webdriver.chrome.service.Service(executable_path=binary_yandex_driver_file) #v4.10+
#service = webdriver.ChromeService(executable_path=binary_yandex_driver_file) #v4.11+

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
driver.get('https://yandex.ru')
driver.quit()
```

[См. подробнее](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76550727/21324434)

Comment: Спасибо, но пока не работает, а откуда берется ChromeService? 
AttributeError: module 'selenium.webdriver' has no attribute 'ChromeService'

Comment: from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
удалось так запустить, спасибо, и подскажи еще, при работе в отличии от хрома валится куча ошибок, они не влияют ни на что?

Comment: @ЮрийШкитский, да, действительно. У меня 4.11, а там были добавлены дополнительные шорткаты к ChromeService

Answer (score 0):

Я делаю примерно так:

```
const chromeDriver = require("chromedriver");
const fs = require("fs");
const webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');

const {Builder, By, Key, until} = require('selenium-webdriver');


var chrome = require("selenium-webdriver/chrome"); 
var chromeOptions = new chrome.Options();
    chromeOptions.addArguments("test-tygospe");
    chromeOptions.addArguments("safebrowsing-disable-download-protection");
    //chromeOptions.addArguments("--headless"); //не показывать браузер
   
async function parse() {
  binary_yandex_driver_file = 'yandexdriver.exe';    
  var service = new chrome.ServiceBuilder(binary_yandex_driver_file).build();
  chrome.setDefaultService(service);
  let driver = await new Builder().forBrowser('chrome').setChromeOptions(chromeOptions).build();
}();
```